# Devexpress xtrareport pivot grid grand total for the percentage column

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I have 3 columns like target, sales, percentage (sales/target *100). When i have shown these three columns in the devexperss xtrareport pivot grid the grand total percentage is just taking the sum of the columns. i want to show the percentage of the sum of sales / sum of target in both row and column grand total.
[Check the attached excel sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FZddtBUJS_Bl_LdzycwUnpRxhxxXuany/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104077738409713435309&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this with the following steps.

1. Create a new unbounded column
2. Set the Summary type as "Custom"
3. Set the Unbound Expression formula as "Sales/Target*100"
4. Set the Unbound Expression Mode as "Use Summary Value"
5. Set the Unbound Type as Decimal
6. Add that new column into the data area.